# Что должен знать архитектор?

Tags: работа, архитектура

Какие квалификационные требования к архитектору в контексте [Systems Architect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_architect)?

Comment: у архитектора должна быть комната с кучей мониторов

Comment: Дружить с физикой и математикой- а потом включать архикад)

Comment: Я думаю, что когда вы станете архитектором (если им станете), то данный вопрос отпадет автоматически. Хотя каждый программист, в какой степени, по-своему архитектор.

Comment: >каждый программист, в какой степени, по-своему архитектор

и в чем же именно?

Comment: @DreamChild, очевидно же, в проектировании своих собственных разработок, минимум)

Comment: А я поставлю минус за столь коротко заданный вопрос.
Ибо понимать вопрос по тегам - это неправильно.
Как такового понятия архитектор в web нет. есть инженеры-админы -занимаются серверами, есть инженеры-программисты занимаются структурой приложения и т.д. и т.п. а кто такие архитекторы? Они вроде как строят, точнее придумывают или что то там делают с домами и строениями.

Comment: Спасибо, что аргументировали минус.

Comment: @alex91, это не просто аргументированный минус, это призыв задать вопрос нормально. Пока еще минусов аргументированных не накидали.

Answer (score 3):

1. Архитектор должен иметь способность к абстрактному мышлению, при этом одновременно не слишком сильно отрываться от реальности в виде конкретных людей, технологий, железок и проч.
2. В общем смысле архитектор должен уметь проектировать систему от общего к частному, с тем чтобы общая задача была разбита на отдельные детали/элементы понятные кодерам в самой нижней ступени иерархии.

Отсюда следует, что архитектор должен знать технологии, железки (software/hardware), должен знать чисто менеджерские функции: как-то делегирование, контроль, постановка задачи. Должен знать как управлять проектами - особливо т.н. итерационное/agile управление (хотя две последние это в основном функции манагеров прожектов).

Comment: согласен с пунктом 2. первый пункт должны знать все программисты и менеджеры, связанные с программированием.

Answer (score 1):

Вы должны знать и употреблять много красивых слов: паттерн, UML, облако, HTML 5, социальность, нереляционные базы данных, высокие нагрузки.

Вы должны называть любое кодирование «тривиальной технической деталью».

Comment: я так понимаю, плюсы проставили те, кто не понимает, зачем "эти архитекторы" нужны?:)

Comment: @KoVadim: why so serious?